# How to set vertical align middle for a div enclose another div

Tags: html, css

I have two div (first_div and second_div) enclose in another div in my html page .

I want to set vertical align middle to first_div content.

My html similar to:

```
<div class="outer_div">
<div class="first_div">
   Clean and Simple...<br>
    Moderna
</div>
<div class="second_div">
  Ad pro quidam prodesset conceptam. Accommodare vituperatoribus ius cu, eu sea sale partem legimus, vel ea noluisse phaedrum mediocrem. Ad pro quidam prodesset
  conceptam. Accommodare vituperatoribus ius cu, eu sea sale partem legimus, vel ea noluisse phaedrum mediocrem. Et eam quot autem propriae. Nibh detraxit vix id, et unum graeco his, eu quodsi delectus eum. Cu probatus rationibus eum, ne tamquam omittantur neglegentur nam.
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.first_div, .second_div
{
  float:left;
  width:48%;
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: You mean you want to align `first_div` with `second_div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdgOEW

```
<div class="outer_div">
    <div class="first_div">
        First div
    </div>
    <div class="second_div">
       Second div
    </div>
</div>

.first_div, .second_div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
  background: #CCC;
  width: 50%;
}

.second_div{
  background: #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Please check my edited html in question , your answer not working.

Comment: Okay, that changes things. Well, you don't need the floats. Check my updated demo.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer_div {

  border: solid 1px #ccc;

  padding: 20px;

  float: left;

  width: 100%;

}

.first_div {

  height: 45px;

  line-height: 45px;

  background-color: red;

}

.first_div,

.second_div {

  float: left;

  width: 48%;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="first_div">
    DIV 1 content
  </div>
  <div class="second_div">
    DIV 2 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.outer_div {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.first_div {
  background-color: red;
}
.first_div,
.second_div {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* keeps it inline*/
  width: 48%;
  /*remove float; as it creates problem for vertical-align*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="first_div">
    DIV 1 content
  </div>
  <div class="second_div">
    conceptam. Accommodare vituperatoribus ius cu, eu sea sale partem legimus, vel ea noluisse phaedrum mediocrem. Et eam quot autem propriae. Nibh detraxit vix id, et unum graeco his, eu quodsi delectus eum. Cu probatus rationibus eum, ne tamquam omittantur
    neglegentur nam. conceptam. Accommodare vituperatoribus ius cu, eu sea sale partem legimus, vel ea noluisse phaedrum mediocrem. Et eam quot autem propriae. Nibh detraxit vix id, et unum graeco his, eu quodsi delectus eum. Cu probatus rationibus eum,
    ne tamquam omittantur neglegentur nam.

  </div>
</div>
```

this way using `display:inline-block`you can get `vertical-align:middle` or you can also try, `display:table-cell` method, then you'll get equal height as well.